# Custom variable for server URI collection when making OpenAPI specification in Postman

Tags: postman, openapi

I'm making API in postman (APIs icon). In `index.yaml` definition I have:

```
openapi: "3.1.0"
info:
    version: "1.0.0"
    title: "Web Services"
servers:
    - url: 'https://example.com'

paths:
    /v1/GetData:
```

I tried to replace https://example.com with in url section with  `{{url}}` or `{url}` in hope to get:
[image]

in generated collection, instead it's allways
`{{baseUrl}}/v1/GetData`

I need a solution to generate that Collection from `yaml` with `{{url}}` from start not by edition generated Collection after fact.